# Если грузить изображение с других источников, скорость загрузки увеличится?

Tags: оптимизация-сайтов

Если грузить изображение с других источников (к примеру указав в `<img src=...>` конкретную сылку), скорость загрузки увеличится?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну это снижает нагрузку на твой сервер, также изображения (да и не только, можно и скрипты и стили) подключенные через определенную ссылку грузятся параллельно что также существенно уменьшает загрузку, только нужно учитывать что если ссылка будет битой то ничего не загрузиться.

Но такую подгрузку используют для больших сайтов, если у тебя маленький одностраничник, лэндинг то не стоит использовать такую возможность, это может и немного задерживать загрузку по той причине например: на сайте откуда ты берешь изображения сейчас идут технические работы.. В итоге ни одно изображение на твоем сайте не откроется по данной причине.

Но а так, да, скорость загрузки увеличивается и нагрузки на твой сервер уменьшается.

Один явный пример такой подгрузки изображений, это гугл/яндекс карты.

Answer (score 0):

В принципе да. Протокол *HTTP 1.1* позволяет так называемое *persistent connection*, что значит *более чем один request/response* для одной HTTP связи.

И так для изображения с *других* источников должно составить *новой* HTTP связь, пока из *этого самого* нет.